# Renewing a Session Token in Mediafire API Calls Using Java

Tags: java, api, mediafire

I'm practicing web services programming with the Mediafire API. I'm able to get info using version 1 token. Is there anyway to automate session token renewal after ten minutes in my code? Currently, I'm just re-running my build when I need a new token.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the API call to renew session token in your code when you receive a "session token invalid or expired" response.

The API uri is:

```
/api/user/renew_session_token.php
```

parameters:

```
session_token (the session token)
response_format (your preferred response format)
```

The API description:

> Refreshes the lifespan of a Session Token v1 session token to ten
>   minutes or returns a new Session Token v1 session token with a
>   lifespan of ten minutes. Session tokens less than five minutes old are
>   returned without being refreshed.